# Post jpeg data to URL to image stream

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jpeg, webcam, h.264

I am trying to set up a video feed from a microcontroller system.  I am able to get data in JPEG format from an image sensor and post it to my webserver.  I wish to display the stream of images that will be continually posted to the server in the form of a webcam stream.

I have no idea where to start to get decent playback speed.  How would I go about doing this without having a full page refresh every time the image is posted?

Comment: Update the `src` attribute of an `<img>` tag with an interval timer?

Comment: Is that fast enough for 30fps?

Comment: Probably not. If you really want to stream video, you'd need to re-encode the image stream on the server. Video formats involve various compression techniques so that they contain a lot less data than a simple stream of JPEG images. (I don't know exactly how you'd go about re-encoding the images, but I would be surprised if there weren't various options available.)